# Slow Performance in Excel Addin (C#/ExcelDna)

Tags: excel, add-in, office-addins, assembly-binding-redirect

We have an Excel Addin developed in C# and integrated with ExcelDna.
It worked fine for many years.
But now for one customer it runs with slow performance.
I added some logging and can't figure out any significant slow part in the code.
It seems that in general every piece of code is a bit slower and for longer running tasks the total loss of time is significant.

The Addin runs in its own AppDomain and because of some Nuget dependencies, we use AssemblyRedirects specified in the config file of the Addin, which is used by the AppDomain.

And now the funny/weird finding:
My colleague added those Redirects to the Excel.exe.config and voila: it runs fast.

What the heck is going on here?
Well, it kinda fixed the problem, but of course we don't wanna manipulate the config file of Excel.

We figured out, that if only one of these two redirects exist in the Excel.exe.config, the Addin runs fast:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Any help on that is appreciated.